# Retrieve neighborhood given an address Google Maps

Tags: java, maps

Google maps recognizes the boundaries of neighborhoods already. How would I (without manually plotting the polygon on a map) determine if a given address (point) lies in this neighborhood? I'm looking at a giant list of properties for my work and I have to manually check if properties lie in certain neighborhoods given just the address. Maybe someone has been faced with this kind of problem.

In this example. Gage Park, Chicago, IL(note the seemingly square shape- this is the most square I could find, other neighborhoods are more complex):

Pseudo call would eventually look something like:

```
Address a = "1234 Main St"
boolean b = a.IsAddressIn("Gage Park");
```

[image]

Comment: If you had a postal code, you may be able to link the postal code with the corresponding neighborhood? Otherwise I don't think there's a way for an address to know which neighborhood it's in without what you mentioned (plotting a polygon).

Comment: Postal codes are a good thought, but some postal codes span several neighborhoods. Conversely, some neighborhoods can span several postal codes.

Comment: Yea, in the case of addresses, you'd essentially need a list of addresses that correspond with each neighborhood in order to accurately compare the two. Even if that dataset did exist (which I'm sure it does) that seems like a large dataset for what your trying to achieve. ArcGIS's Spatial Analyst tool does point-to-polygon analysis, you might want to look into that. Let me know if you figure out another way to accomplish this!